Mac QGIS 3.34.3 can installed QGIS resource sharing but can't install the collection
Mac QGIS 3.34.3 can installed QGIS resource sharing, but can't install the collection. When I clicked install, it shows:
Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /alinager/qgis-styles.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

How to fix this?

Seems like you have a problem with certificates to securely reach GitHub. Are you in a company network or have some security tools installed that mess with certificates?
